# Missing adobe acrobat browser control type library 1.0 reference

Tags: ms-access, adobe

I have imported an access database and front end form to my local.

I am working through the various issues and one I have been unable to solve is a missing reference. I am not getting any issues or errors to report here that directly link back to this but having said that i don't like having 'Missing references' in my ref list.

Missing reference when i go to "Tools"->"References...". shows:
"Adobe Acrobat Browser Control Type Lib 1.0".

My system is 64 bit, I suspect the previous host was 32 bit and this has been indicated as an issue. I see some docs show no 64 bit alternative.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you need it? Late binding is nearly always better.

Comment: I hate to have to ask this, but did you scroll down the list of available references to see if there was a newer version available? I have 'Adobe Acrobat 7.0 Browser Control Type Library 1.0'

Comment: From the following link, it mentions '...you can't use 64-bit Office with 32-bit DLL's...' and '... there is no 64-bit DLL for Adobe available...'   
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6e1753aa-b3c6-4a2e-9951-7d70a944e16b/ms-office-64-bit-vba-adobe-acrobat-reader-pdf-control?forum=isvvba
Yet Adobe says they have 64-bit in Release 11.xxx:  https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/vb-60-64-bit-issue-11007.html